# Django Rest Framework: Rest-auth email verification - Server Error 500

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, smtp, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to enable email verification on Django Rest Framework with rest-auth.

It works when I use console.Backend, however when I enable real emails via smtp, it gives me a Server Error 500 after registration. I'm using the same smtp settings as my node.js mail server which works perfectly, so I'm positive the smtp settings are correct.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this? I'm not sure what other code is responsible for this, please let me know if I need to provide something else.

Here are the relevant settings:

```
REST_SESSION_LOGIN = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 3

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None

LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = False

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 6,
        }
    },
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.zxcs.nl'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@xxxxx.nl'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 465 appears to be SSL, not TLS so changing

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

to

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

fixed it :)